# Creating new line within a String in HTML

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have string like as follow, which is generated in mvc controller and display in a view within a table cell. S020050A,S020050B,S020050C,S020050D,S020050E,S020050F
,S020050G,S020050H,S020050I,S020050J,S020050K,S020050L

As I want to wrap the text on every 5 words, I have pushed
tag 
 on every 5 words, so that string look like as follow
S020050A,S020050B,S020050C,S020050D,S020050E,
S020050F
,S020050G,S020050H,S020050I
,S020050J,S020050K,S020050L

I am intended to break the line from there, but in a view it just shows as it is, 
 tag not interpreted as new line but simply as a part of string

I tried putting Environment.Newline and /n as well, when I did this in simple html page, it worked, so I believe it asp.net own mechanism which suppress 
 tag, how I can make 
 tag interpreted as new line?

Comment: If possible add the code

Comment: The important bit, what tag you have inserted, does not show in your question. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and make sure we can see the relevant code, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it, from controller code (back end) add -> \n instead 
 where you want line break and then in view use this style ->
style="white-space: pre-line"